# Invalid block tag on line 21: 'transaction'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting the error on the transaction models, not sure what i am missing. See the error below i am on the view

```
from django.db import models

class Status(models.Model):
description = models.TextField()
created_at  = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at  = models.DateTimeField()
class Meta:
    db_table = "status"

def __str__(self):
    return self.description

class User(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
created_at  = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at  = models.DateTimeField()
signed_agreement = models.BooleanField()
class Meta:
    db_table = "users"

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Inventory(models.Model):
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField()
created_at  = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at  = models.DateTimeField()
class Meta:
    db_table = "inventory"

def __str__(self):
    return self.description

class Transaction(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='inventory')        
checkout_time = models.DateTimeField()
scheduled_checkin_time = models.DateTimeField()
actual_checkin_time = models.DateTimeField()
created_at  = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at  = models.DateTimeField()
class Meta:
    db_table = "transactions"

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.inventory.description
```

[image]

[image]

Added the keyword for for, now its giving the error on the model

## Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-09-03 13:26

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Inventory',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('description', models.TextField()),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField()),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'inventory',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Status',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('description', models.TextField()),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField()),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'status',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='User',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('email', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128)),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('signed_agreement', models.BooleanField()),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'users',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Transaction',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('checkout_time', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('scheduled_checkin_time', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('actual_checkin_time', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField()),
            ('inventory', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='checkout.Inventory')),
            ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='checkout.User')),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'transactions',
        },
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='inventory',
        name='status',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='checkout.Status'),
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your home.html you missed to write "for" in your for loop.
Instead of

```
{% transaction in user.transaction_set.all %}
```

Write this

```
{% for transaction in user.transaction_set.all %}
```

Comment: are you using transactions.id somehere in your template?

Comment: {% for transaction in transactions %}
            <tr>

                <td>{{ transaction.user.first_name }}</td>
  <td></td>
                <td>{{ transaction.checkout_time }}</td>
  <td></td>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: I don't use ID in the template

Comment: what is in transactions?

Comment: why not using user.transaction_set.all ?

Comment: I have pasted the model in question

Comment: Not sure what are asking ?

Comment: try to learning, that's why trying different approach. I am passing user and transaction in the view.

Comment: okay,add the code of views.py in your question,it will be then easy to find where the problem is

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404

from .models import User
from .models import Transaction

def home(request):
    user =  User.objects.all()
    transactions =  Transaction.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'user': user, 'transactions': transactions})

Comment: all the code seems fine,have you done makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: Add the migrations

Comment: do a clean makemigrations and migrate,then it will work. I think the id related error is the issue due to incorrect migrations